# Importing modules used in a package in __init__.py

Tags: python

I have the following directory structure:

```
funniest/
    setup.py
    funniest/ 
          __init__.py
          ModuleA.py
          ModuleB.py
```

```
# __init__.py
from numba import jit

from .ModuleA import ClassA
```

```
# ModuleA.py
import funniest.ModuleB

class ClassA():
    pass
```

```
# ModuleB.py
@jit
def f():
    pass
```

However, when importing the module, I get the error message:

```
>>> import funniest
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
File "/home/domi89/Dropbox/Python_Projects/funniest/funniest  /__init__.py", line 2, in <module>
from .ModuleA import ClassA
File "/home/domi89/Dropbox/Python_Projects/funniest/funniest /ModuleA.py", line 1, in <module>
import funniest.ModuleB
File "/home/domi89/Dropbox/Python_Projects/funniest/funniest/ModuleB.py", line 1, in <module>
@jit
NameError: name 'jit' is not defined
```

I cannot understand why this happends, because when `__init__.py` get executed first, the first thing it does is importing `from numba import jit`. So why is `jit` not defined when it comes to function `f` in `ModuleB`?

Comment: You need to import the things you're using *in B*, not just at the module level.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The name `jit` is not known inside `ModuleB`. Python imports doesn't work like C/C++ includes that roll-out the code in place of the `import`. A new module creates a new namespace with a map inside - a map with functions, classes, etc.

So when you did `import funniest`, you created new map entry in the current namespace, like: `{..., funniest: {}, ...}`.  By importing `funniest`, you imported `jit` and `ClassA`, so from the place when you imported the `funniest` module, you have access to such map: `funniest: {jit: {..}, ClassA: {...}}`.

In `ModuleA` you imported `ModuleB`, so in `ModuleA` you have new variable `ModuleB:{...}` with content of `ModuleB`. But here you don't see the `funniest` map - it is in other level in hierarchy.

And in `ModuleB`, you don't see `funniest` and `ClassA` maps (namespaces - and whatever you like to call it;)).

Comment: You nicely broke it down, thank you. So it actually makes no sense to put import statesment in the `__init__.py` file if I want them to used inside the package, not making them available to the user importing the package?

Comment: Yes, for internal use inside package, the 'import' in __init__.py has no effect. But outside as you pointed - it is very useful ;)

Answer (score 7):

The imports you put in `funniest/__init__.py` are only imported when you do `import funniest`, not automatically inside submodules. So `ModuleB` doesn't know about `jit`.

What you need to do here is to move `from numba import jit` from `__init__.py` to `ModuleB.py`.

Comment: So in generally, if I create a package composed of different modules, each individual module needs its own imports at the top of the file? There is no possibility of importing stuff once for all modules?

Comment: @Dominik: Exactly.  The modules are separate namespaces.  As I said in a comment on another answer (now deleted), each module is responsible for importing its own dependencies.  One common automated test is to `import name` and then exit, for each _name_.py file in your project --- they should each import cleanly, even with nothing else imported before or after.

Comment: @Dominik - this is interesting source to have a clear view:
https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/modules.html

Comment: @Dominik:  I _have_ seen some people collect lots of imports in single file called something like utils.py, and then have all their other modules `import .utils`.  I think that's still more work than just a handful of imports in each .py file... and it results in _everything_ imported into modules that don't need it.  I think it's just weird when a module like log.py imports NumPy and SciPy and NLTK and...

Comment: @KevinJ.Chase Got it. I think then I need to revise my file structure. I have broken down things into too many interrelated modules and the imports are driving my crazy now, while essentially it could be one single module (but who wants to manage a couple of thousand lines of code in a single file?)